# Fading two images into each other on button click?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create a banner ad. There's a collapsed version that has an expand button and then the expanded, bigger version has a collapse button to go back to it's previous state. I've been asked to do this without using external javascript libraries and only using JS and CSS. I'm trying to do it with JS and CSS animations right now, but I'm having a hard time. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong and help me get on the path to fixing my problem?

[Here's a link to the code I have going now.](http://codepen.io/rawaid/pen/KdqwGE)

```
function fade(btnElement) {


if (btnElement.id == "expandButton"){
    console.log("expand!");
    document.getElementById("myImg").className = "fade-out";
    document.getElementById("myImg").display = "none";
    document.getElementById("myImg2").display = "block";
    document.getElementById("myImg2").className = "fade-in";
    console.log(document.getElementById("myImg2").display);



}

else {
    document.getElementById("myImg2").className = "fade-in";
    btnElement.value = "Fade Out";
}
```

}

I can get the first image to fade out, but I can't seem to get the second image to fade in...

EDIT: so, I have the images switching back and forth, but that was never really a problem for me... The problem I'm having is making them fade into each other via button click using CSS transitions. Can anyone help?

Comment: for starters, you need to specify .style.property for css properties.

Comment: If you check the codepen link, I'm pretty sure I've set the css style properties. I set myImg2's display  to "none" and myImg's to "block". Is there something I'm doing wrong there?


EDIT: omg I feel so dumb... I know what you mean now. I got them to change, but now the fading is gone... how can I get them to properly fade?

Comment: You can do this just using Css (and a little js), If I were you, I would add a class named 'clicked' on the container of your banner ad when it is clicked and then do all the fading stuff with opacity, absolute positioning etc.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the second image stays hidden is because `document.getElementById("myImg2").display` does nothing and the css rule you have written for `#myImg2` remains. try instead `document.getElementById("myImg2").style.display` And you will the the element display block. Not sure about the fade though. That didn't seem to work appropriately.